# macOS Server 5.3 Calendar pg_ctl not starting

Tags: macos, postgresql, server, calendar, synchronization

After updating macOS Server to 5.3 (running on macOS 10.12.4) my Calendar & Contacts have stopped syncing.

It seems that it's having trouble starting `Postgres for cluster /Library/Server/Calendar and Contacts/Data/Database.xpg/cluster.pg` and possibly trouble with the agent too.

The GUI seems to think that the Calendar & Contacts services have started and are available, but when I run `$ sudo serveradmin fullstatus calendar` from the command line I get:

```
calendar:setStateVersion = 1
calendar:readWriteSettingsVersion = 1
calendar:state = "STARTING"
calendar:contactsState = "STARTING"
calendar:calendarState = "STARTING"
```

System log is being spammed with:

```
Apr 22 11:58:42 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.calendarserver.agent[44649]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Apr 22 11:58:42 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.calendarserver.agent): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Apr 22 11:58:52 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.calendarserver.agent[44659]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Apr 22 11:58:52 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.calendarserver.agent): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Apr 22 11:59:02 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.calendarserver.agent[44668]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Apr 22 11:59:02 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.calendarserver.agent): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Apr 22 11:59:07 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.calendarserver.calendarserver[44676]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Apr 22 11:59:07 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.calendarserver.calendarserver): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 60 seconds.
```

Here's the output of `$ sudo /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin/calendarserver_diagnose`

Any ideas?

```
OS Build: 16E195
Server Build: 16S4123    

/Library/Server/Preferences/Calendar.plist exists and can be parsed
Prefs plist says ServerRoot directory is: /Library/Server/Calendar and Contacts
ServerRoot volume ok
/Library/Server/Calendar and Contacts/Config/caldavd-system.plist exists and can be parsed
/Library/Server/Calendar and Contacts/Config/caldavd-user.plist does not exist    

Configuration:    

Calendar and Contacts service processes:
USER              PID  %CPU %MEM    RSS  ELAPSED STARTED                      COMMAND
root            42554   0.0  0.1  11072    07:49 Sat 22 Apr 11:32:16 2017     servermgr_calendar        

Serverd status:
org.calendarserver.agent is enabled
org.calendarserver.calendarserver is enabled
org.calendarserver.relocate is enabled    

Disk space on boot volume:
Filesystem   Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1   999G   777G   222G    78% 8520180 4286447099    0%   /    

Disk space on service data volume:
Filesystem   Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1   999G   777G   222G    78% 8520180 4286447099    0%   /    

Disk space used by Calendar and Contacts service:
20K  /Library/Server/Calendar and Contacts/Config
1014M /Library/Server/Calendar and Contacts/Data
200M  /Library/Server/Calendar and Contacts/Logs    


Postgres status for cluster /Library/Server/Calendar and Contacts/Data/Database.xpg/cluster.pg:
pg_ctl: no server running    


Agent:
Attempting to send a request to the agent...
Can't connect to agent: timed out    

Server connection:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin/calendarserver_diagnose", line 14, in <module>
    load_entry_point('CalendarServer==9.1a1.dev0+56b4197875debefef19d9c19840f903a8e480c88.head', 'console_scripts', 'calendarserver_diagnose')()
  File "/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/Library/CalendarServer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/calendarserver/tools/diagnose.py", line 145, in main
    connectToCaldavd(keys)
  File "/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/Library/CalendarServer/lib/python2.7/site-packages/calendarserver/tools/diagnose.py", line 584, in connectToCaldavd
    url = "https://{host}/principals/".format(host=keys["ServerHostName"])
KeyError: 'ServerHostName'
```

Comment: run `sudo find / -name PG_VERSION` to find the data_dir and then start the server with `pg_ctl -D FOUND_PATH` ?..

Comment: Amazing thank you - getting closer:

`$ sudo -u _calendar pg_ctl start -D .
server starting
$ FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.4, which is not compatible with this version 9.6.3.`

So now I guess I need to work out the command to upgrade from 9.4 to 9.6.3.

Comment: yes, but before `pg_upgrade` - make sure you don't have 9.4 installed - if I get it right you have data - where it came from?..

Comment: Location: `/Library/Server/Calendar\ and\ Contacts/Data/Database.xpg/cluster.pg/`

Comment: `$ postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.6.3`

Comment: `sudo find / -name pg_ctl` - how many versions you have installed?..

Comment: Doesn't look like I have 9.4 - should I do a `pg_dumpall`?

`/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/postgresql9.0/pg_ctl
/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/postgresql9.1/pg_ctl
/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/postgresql9.2/pg_ctl
/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/postgresql9.3/pg_ctl
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/bin/pg_ctl
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.2/bin/pg_ctl
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.3/bin/pg_ctl`

Comment: that's funny :) you have server 9.[0-3] and 9.6 and yet you have data  for 9.4... how did you get there?.. If I were you I'd just install postgres 9.4 and would try to consume data_directory with it

Comment: Okay, I'll try installing 9.4. What would be the 'consume data_directory' command?

Comment: `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.3/bin/pg_ctl -D /Library/Server/Calendar\ and\ Contacts/Data/Database.xpg/cluster.pg/` I suppose

Comment: `$ sudo -u _calendar /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql\@9.4/9.4.12/bin/pg_ctl -D cluster.pg/`

`pg_ctl: no operation specified`

Did you mean to include start?

Comment: Yes. Surely. :)

Comment: I tried running `sudo -u _calendar /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin/pg_upgrade -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql\@9.4/9.4.12/bin/ -B /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin -d /Library/Server/Calendar\ and\ Contacts/Data/Database.xpg/broken-cluster.pg/ -D /Library/Server/Calendar\ and\ Contacts/Data/Database.xpg/cluster.pg`

But got the error `connection to database failed: FATAL:  role "_calendar" does not exist`

Comment: So here's where 9.4 lives. In the Server.app directory. `/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin/pg_ctl --version
pg_ctl (PostgreSQL) 9.4.6`

Which means it's not a failed upgrade problem.. there's something else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145152/discussion-between-vao-tsun-and-sighmon).

Comment: ```/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin/pg_ctl -D /Library/Server/Calendar\ and\ Contacts/Data/Database.xpg/cluster.pg start```
exact error please